# Wizard quest entry

Tags: nethack

I'm an elf wizard with good stats, lots of spells, resistances and intrinsics and level 15. I'm new to nethack but have been spoiling quite a bit. Does having teleport control interfere with the teleport for the quest or am I not high enough level? I got the telepathic message but the only teleporter I can find triggered teleport control.

Answer (score 5):

The entrance to the quest is a magic portal, not a teleporter, so anything to do with teleportation doesn't have any effect whatsoever.

You can locate the portal with a crystal ball, liberal use of Detect Unseen or a wand of secret door detection, a cursed scroll of gold detection, or a non-cursed confused scroll of gold detection.

But what I usually do is just walk on every tile on the level with shift-move until I hit it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can still use the quest teleporter. IIRC, it is not the usual colour of teleportation traps. You can use that to make sure that what you've find is not the right one.

Answer (score 1):

To enter the [quest level](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Quest), you need to be experience level 14 or higher. Teleport control does not interfere with entering the quest level. Presumably you have not found the actual portal, just a teleport trap that happens to be on the same level.